# Override property observer

Tags: swift, properties, overriding, didset

When I override the function `noise`, the function gets replaced by the new one. But when I override a property with an observer, the old and new value gets both executed.

In playground:

```
class Vehicle {
    func noise(sound: String) {
        println("Vehicle sound sounds like \(sound)")
    }
}

class Train: Vehicle {
    override func noise(sound: String) {
        println("A train does: \(sound)")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
var oldTrain = Train()
bulletTrain.noise("tjoek tjoek") // Prints: "A train does: tjoek tjoek"
```

But when I do the same with an property with an observer:

In playground:

```
class Foo {
    var something: Int! {
        didSet {
            println("vroom")
        }
    }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    override var something: Int! {
        didSet {
            println("toot toot")
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
var foobar = Bar()
foobar.something = 3 // Prints: "vroom" & "toot toot"
```

So how am I supposed to override a property with an observer and how to prevent the old values to be executed as well?

Comment: It seems no way to prevent the old property observer to be executed.

Comment: it's amazing you cannot override `didSet`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can override the `set` and `get` part of the property and move your `println` there. This way Swift won't call the original code -- unless you call super.

```
class Foo {
    private var _something: Int!

    var something: Int! {
        get {
            return _something
        }
        set {
            _something = newValue
            println("vroom")
        }
    }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    override var something: Int! {
        get {
            return _something
        }
        set {
            _something = newValue
            println("toot toot")
        }
    }
}
```

That's not pretty, though.

Here's a better -- and simpler -- solution:

```
class Foo {
    var something: Int! {
        didSet {
            somethingWasSet()
        }
    }

    func somethingWasSet() {
        println("vroom")
    }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    override func somethingWasSet() {
        println("toot toot")
    }
}
```

Since there is no way to "override" the `didSet`, what remains is overriding a secondary function especially created for that purpose.

Comment: As suggested by @nhgrif, I combined the two solutions into a single answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a bunch. Strange you can't just override `didSet`. As I've read, apple fixed some bugs related to `didSet` not so long ago. I got the feeling they still have many bugs to fix regarding `didSet`.

Comment: I don't think allowing property observers to be overridden is likely to be in the works at any point...

Answer (score 4):

From the [Swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)

> The willSet and didSet observers of superclass properties are called when a property is set in a subclass initializer, after the superclass initializer has been called. They are not called while a class is setting its own properties, before the superclass initializer has been called.

Answer (score 0):

Observers in subclasses are only added to the one defined in the superclass.

From official documentation: [Overriding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html#ID196)

> **Overriding Properties**
>
> You can override an inherited instance or type
> property to provide your own custom getter and setter for that
> property, **or to add property observers** to enable the overriding
> property to observe when the underlying property value changes.